# How to get order history on binance with the api

Tags: python, binance-api-client

i would like to have each new completed order on a binance account. Like when i have a new trade completed i would like to get informations about it. Do you the function for that i can't find it in the doc of binance api. Thanks for yours answers.

Comment: i just discover a function that might be perfect but it return [ ] (empty list)
When i write: client.futures_account_trades(symbol="BTCUSDT") 
And ofc i have trade on my account on this pair

Comment: api for Order History not exist in Binance.. maybe in future..

Comment: But we can use GET /fapi/v1/userTrades (Trade History) if realizedPnl == "0" its entry point, if 0> its Take Profit if 0< its Stop Loss